# If I have guests at my entrance and in my queue, which are chosen first?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza

When I have both guests at my entrance and in my queue (Mii Plaza Premium), from which one will the guests be chosen when I finished all my games and start up Mii Plaza? Or does it give me a choice?

Lets say, for example, that I have 6 Mii's in at the entrance and that I have 10 Mii's in my Mii Plaza Premium queue. I'm currently trying to only play the games with at least 10 Mii's. When I have all games finished with the current batch of people, and I start up Mii Plaza, what will happen? Will the 6 Mii's at the default entrance show up, will the 10 Mii's in my Mii Plaza Premium queue show up or will I get a choice between the two?

Comment: If I got your problem, each time you receive guests you can always send them to your queue in order to have a 10 Mii's group for your games. If you don't "enqueue" them, the games choses before the Mii's at the entrance.

Comment: So, if all games are already played with my previous batch of Mii's, it asks me if I want to send my current Mii's to my queue and then automatically uses the Mii's in my queue?

Comment: You can send them in the queue whenever you want, and you can still play with the current Miis in your plaza, then, in any moment, you can receive another batch of Miis from the queue and start again.